# jQuery Overlay Hover Flashing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

I want to make it so when the `img` is hovered, an overlay to appear.  It works okay, but it keeps flashing.  I searched around here, and people seem to have had the same problem; however, the solution involved `.toggle()`, which has been depreciated.

```
$(".box img").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).next(".overlay").fadeIn(300);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).next(".overlay").fadeOut(300);
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5jEr/621/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because when the `.overlay` div fades in, that gets in between your mouse cursor and the underlying `img` element, triggering the `.mouseleave` function.

There are probably several ways of resolving this, but here's one:

Add `opacity: 0` to your `.overlay` class. Then use this in your JS:

```
$(".box .overlay").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 300)
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 300)
});
```

And the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/g5jEr/623/) (updated).

Comment: Is this valid jQuery? `$("this img")`  How do you use `this` when using child selectors?

Comment: @Matthew "next" is not a child selector. Even in their documentation (http://api.jquery.com/next/), they use the next function on a `button` element, which—like `img`—would presumably not have any children.

Comment: @Matthew I noticed that. Just updated with fully satisfactory solution. Essentially, by setting `opacity: 0`, you are able to trigger the `mouseover` event on the invisible `.overlay` div.